# Efficient way to delete/update entities in EF Core 7 by a list of conditions

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core, ef-core-7.0

I need to delete/update a given number of rows of a table.

In one I solved it like this:

```
  await context.MyItems
    .Where(x => itemsIds.Contains(x.Id))
    .ExecuteUpdateAsync(f => f.SetProperty(x => x.State, state));
```

which allows me to update the items ina given list of ids (1,2,5,7, ...)

But I am not sure how to do the same in a table where I need to filter not by a list of ids, but by a list of multiple properties:

```
var itemsToUpdate = new List<Identifier>(){ ....}
```

And identifier is

```
public class Identifier
{
    DateTime date {get;set;}
    string code {get;set;}
    string owner {get;set;}
    
}
```

Any idea of how to do this efficienly in EF Core? Cause I am thinking that I got not other solution but a Stored Procedure :-(

To make it clearer, original function:

```
public async Task UpdateItemsAsync(IList<long> Ids, ItemStatus state)
{
    await context.myItems
        .Where(x => Ids.Contains(x.Id))
         .ExecuteUpdateAsync(f => f.SetProperty(x => x.State, state));
}
```

New function:

```
public async Task UpdateItemsAsync(IList<Identifier> Ids, ItemStatus state)
{
   //can´t figure out how to apply filter here
}
```

Comment: Run it in a loop, executing one delete per loop or build a raw, parameterised SQL string in a loop and build the parameter collection at the same time, then execute

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a Table Valued Parameter for this.

First create a table type

```sql
CREATE TYPE dbo.Identifier AS TABLE (
    date datetime(7),
    code nvarchar(100),
    owner nvarchar(100)
)
```

On EF Core 7 and earlier, because it's a multi-column type, you can't use `context.Database.SqlQuery` on this, you need to add an entity to your model.

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<Identifier>().HasNoKey().ToView(null);
```

Then you can use it like this:

```cs
var table = new DataTable { Columns = {
    { "date", typeof(DateTime) },
    { "code", typeof(string) },
    { "owner", typeof(string) },
};
foreach (var item in items)
{
    table.Add(item.date, item.code, item.owner);
}

// must create this part in a separate step
var itemsTvp = context.Set<Identifier>().FromSqlRaw(
    "SELECT * FROM @tmp",
    new SqlParameter("@tmp", table) { TypeName = "dbo.Identifier", Value = table }
);
//

await context.MyItems
    .Where(x => itemsTvp.Any(t => t.date = x.date && t.code == x.code && t.owner == x.owner)
    .ExecuteUpdateAsync(f => f.SetProperty(x => x.State, state));
```

In EF Core 8 you don't need an entity, you can just use

```cs
var itemsTvp = context.Database.SqlQueryRaw<Identifier>(
```

Comment: Fixed all that, thanks.

Comment: Thanks Charlieface, it looks like what I need. I have a question though. If instead of wanting to update all those rows with the same state value I wanted to update state to the corresponding code value how would I do it? I do not see how to tie the update section to the itemsTvp section

Comment: You would need to create a joined query, something like `await context.MyItems.Join(itemsTvp, i => i.code, t => t.code, (i, t) => new { i, t }) .ExecuteUpdateAsync(f => f.i.SetProperty(x => x.date, f => f.t.date));`

Comment: See also this answer I just wrote on another question https://stackoverflow.com/a/78186768/14868997

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of [Entity Framework Extensions](http://entityframework-extensions.net/)

This library is not free, but the [WhereBulkContains](https://entityframework-extensions.net/where-bulk-contains) method does exactly what you want:

```
await context.MyItems
    .WhereBulkContains(itemsIds, new { x.Id1 , x.Id2 })
    .UpdateFromQuery(f => new Item { State = state });
```

It support multiple kind of list for you `itemsIds` such as

- List
- Entity Type
- Anonymous Type
- Expando Object

And you can use more than one key to make the JOIN [See custom key](https://entityframework-extensions.net/where-bulk-contains#how-can-i-use-a-custom-key)

Answer (score -1):

You could use BulkExtensions for that:  https://github.com/borisdj/EFCore.BulkExtensions

For example:

```
 await context.MyItems
.Where(x => itemsIds.Contains(x.Id))
.BatchUpdateAsync(f => new Item { State = state });
```

In EF7 you have ExecuteUpdate function https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/ef/core/saving/execute-insert-update-delete :

```
  await context.MyItems
.Where(x => itemsIds.Contains(x.Id))
.ExecuteUpdateAsync(setters => setters.SetProperty(b =>b.State, state));
```

Comment: Uhm, this does not answer my question. I need to filter by the conditions in List<Identifier>(), it is not a mere list of ids. There lies the difficulty.  With a list of ids ExecuteUpdateAsync solves my problem without need of third party extensions