# is it possible to set the property value of SetProperty in ExecuteUpdate() from a collection of values

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework-core, sql-update, ef-core-7.0

I am using Entity Framework Core 7, but I am new to this.

My scenario is as follows. Users enter edited information via the UI that is stored in instances of an entity class called `Upload`.

I could potentially have many edited entities, so I was pleased to find the `ExecuteUpdate()` method which would only make one DB call rather than one call for each entity that using `ChangeTracking` and `SaveChanges` would have done.

However, I cannot seem to find a way in code to set the value for each of the edited properties for each respective entity.

Here is my code so far (not working):

```
var editedUploads = editViewModel.SelectedIncomingStatements
                                 .Select((d,Index) => new Upload() { Id = d.Id , BankRoyaltiesReceived = d.BankRoyaltiesReceived, ExchangeRate = d.ExchangeRate, Tag = Index});

var editedUploadIds = editedUploads.Select(u => u.Id).ToHashSet();

var erColl = new Collection<double>(editedUploads.Select(u => u.ExchangeRate).ToList()); 
var rrColl = new Collection<double>(editedUploads.Select(u => u.BankRoyaltiesReceived).ToList());

using (var trans = await ctx.Database.BeginTransactionAsync(cancellationToken))
{
    try
    {
        var q = from u in ctx.Uploads 
                let c = editedUploadIds.Contains(u.Id) 
                where c == true 
                select u;

        await q.ExecuteUpdateAsync(setters => setters.SetProperty(p => p.BankRoyaltiesReceived, u => rrColl[(int)u.Tag]).SetProperty(p => p.ExchangeRate, u => erColl[(int)u.Tag]));

        await trans.CommitAsync(cancellationToken);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        await trans.RollbackAsync(cancellationToken);
        throw;
    }
}
```

The main issue is for me to be able to 'index' out the values from the 2 collections `exColl` and `rrColl` in the `SetProperty`'s so that I am applying the correct edited value for the corresponding `Upload`.

Fortunately, it seems that collections are translated by EF Core so there use seems to be OK. I tested this with collections and hard coded indices which worked. I originally tried with dictionaries, but according to the docs this is not yet permissible.

So where I am at is to supply the collections with indexes that translate ok for EF Core.

As you can see in the code my last attempt was to add a `[NotMapped]` attribute to the `.Tag` property on the `Upload` entity and set this with the index that will be needed from the 2 collections. Sadly, this didn't work since EF translation complains that `.Tag` is `[NotMapped]` !

So, I am stuck with how to set multiple properties for multiple entities using `ExecuteUpdate()`.

I feel I must be missing something obvious since I would think that this scenario is exactly what `ExecuteUpdate()` is for?

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Are you using SQL Server?

Comment: No, I am using a PostgreSql database.

Answer (score 1):

**The below only works in SQL Server.** In Postgres, you can probably do similar by using an array and `NpgsqlDbType.Composite`.

You should use a Table Valued Parameter for this.

First define a Table Type.

```sql
CREATE TYPE dbo.Upload AS TABLE (
  Id bigint PRIMARY KEY,
  BankRoyaltiesReceived decimal(19,9),
  ExchangeRate decimal(19,9)
);
```

In EF Core 8+ you can use `ctx.Database.SqlQuery<Upload>` on this. But for EF Core 7, you need to define it in your model

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<Upload>().HasNoKey.ToView(null);
```

Now you can pass it as a parameter

```cs
var table = new DataTable { Columns = {
    { "Id", typeof(long) },
    { "BankRoyaltiesReceived", typeof(decimal) },
    { "ExchangeRate", typeof(decimal) },
} };

foreach (var d in editViewModel.SelectedIncomingStatements)
{
    table.Add(d.Id, d.BankRoyaltiesReceived, d.ExchangeRate,);
}

// must do this in a separate step from the rest of the query
var tvp = ctx.Set<Upload>.FromSqlRaw(
    "SELECT * FROM @tmp",
    new SqlParameter("@tmp", table) { TypeName = "dbo.Upload" }
);
//

var q =
    from u in ctx.Uploads
    join t in tvp on u.Id = t.Id
    select new { u, t };

await using var trans = await ctx.Database.BeginTransactionAsync(cancellationToken);

await q.ExecuteUpdateAsync(setters => setters
    .SetProperty(ut => ut.u.BankRoyaltiesReceived, ut => u.t.BankRoyaltiesReceived)
    .SetProperty(ut => ut.u.ExchangeRate, ut => ut.t.ExchangeRate);

await trans.CommitAsync(cancellationToken);
```

Note that you don't need to manually rollback on error if you have a `using`. And you don't need a transaction anyway if all you are doing is one big `UPDATE`.

Comment: thank you for the additional comments at the end. I included a transaction as in my actual code I am doing more than the one update, but I removed this additional code for clarity above.