# How can I perform a join operation between an in-memory list and a SQL database table using EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have the following code :

```cs
List<MyComplexObject> listInMemory = new List<MyComplexObject>
{
    new MyComplexObject { Id1 = 1, Id2 = 2, Name = "Name1" },
    new MyComplexObject { Id1 = 3, Id2 = 4, Name = "Name2" }
};

// And a DbSet in your DbContext
public DbSet<MyEntity> MyEntities { get; set; }

// You can join them like this
var result = MyEntities
    .Join(listInMemory, 
          entity => new { entity.Id1, entity.Id2 }, 
          complexObject => new { complexObject.Id1, complexObject.Id2 }, 
          (entity, complexObject) => entity);
```

I'm trying to verify a list of elements that exist in memory against something in my database, but I get this error:

> resultSelector: (entity, complexObject) => entity)' could not be translated

Comment: Use Linq's in-memory `Join` instead.

Comment: It's not what i want I want something like a contain but in sql is there's any thing that's possible
I have alot and alot of data

Comment: This is still not natively supported. It requires third-party libraries, or dedicated code like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78179778/861716).

Comment: can you tell me what kind of library are you refering too @GertArnold

Comment: How big is your in memory list and how big is your table? In order to compare the data need to be local somewhere for some compute to compare it. Either you need to send the list to SQL to compare or pull the database data locally to compare (probably slower)

Comment: @Nick.Mc My Memory List is smaller we are talking about 10 TO 20 element however in the database as for today I can say that we have 1.000.000 row

Comment: You can't join like that. You aren't even using LINQ to query the database, you're using an ORM, EF Core, whose query language is LINQ. That query has to be translated to SQL to run. If you had a list of IDs you could use `.Where(entity=>listOfIds.Contains(entity.Id))` to generate `WHERE ID IN (@id1,@id2,...)`.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I know that the listOfId.Contains would work unfortunately I can't use in my case because I have  two key that i have to verify 
I tried to use a .Where(entity => myList.Any(id = id and id2 = id2 )) but can't be translated either

Comment: As for `any Github Issues or an area of improvement to this question` they'd be low priority even if they existed. EF is an ORM (Object Relational Mapper) not a database driver. It tries to abstract the actual database and give the impression of working with in-memory objects instead of tables and rows. Table-valued parameters are specific to SQL Server. Other databases like PostgreSQL have different features, eg actual arrays. There's no single way to include complex data in a query

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, usually generating join to `VALUES` is enough. For other RDBMS there are another triks.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos
I asked the same question in github I received this response
https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/33414
https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/31237

Comment: So there is an issue, but not a high priority and certainly won't be included in EF Core 9. Pay attention to what roji says. He's the lead developer of NpgSQL (the .NET PostgreSQL driver), which has rich array and complex type support. I'd bet the feature will appear in NpgSQL first and get ported to SQL Server later on

Comment: Also check [this more relevant GH issue](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/11799) on supporting composite keys. It's still open, but if it's high on roji's personal list of features, it's likely to appear as a NpgSQL EF Core extension in some way.